# What's a good frontend to ~500k mails?

Tags: email

So far, I've been using IMAP to read my mail. However, I have about 350k mails by now (accumulated over the last three years) and most email clients are tried don't work with such numbers very well. Opera does an acceptable job, but every now and then it needs to update it local cache database, which can take ages. In case you wonder: I never delete any email (so that I can search them lateron, which I do every now and then)

I was wondering whether there's maybe an entirely different approach to mails. Something like Google Mail (does Google Mail work acceptably with ~500k mails?), but for the intranet. I have considered [Horde IMP](http://www.horde.org/imp/) but I was told it's rather slow as well.

I suspect that some central SQL database with a reasonable web frontend might do the job for me, but I don't know any software which works like that.

Comment: 500K?!  Holy smokes that's a lot of email!!

Comment: That's 300 emails/day. Do you *really* read all of them? Are they mostly spam?

Comment: @muntoo: I read (almost) all of them. The vast majority of them is smaller notifications, like commit notifications of source code repositories. So it's actually possible to skim over them very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

[Roundcube](http://roundcube.net/) is a very nice webmail solution if you're looking for something you host yourself (you mentioned Horde so I assume you are).  IIRC the only limit to the number of messages is disk space.  That being said I have no idea how well it handles such a high number of messages, since the installations I've used it for have all had much lower user quotas.